# Slow SSH connection on embedded platform

Tags: linux, ssh, embedded, sshd, openssh

I am operating an embedded device running the linux core. I have `OpenSHH_4.9p1` installed running in debug mode and trying to establish an SSH connection using PuTTY. After the login screen everything is running fine and snappy. My slow down occurs during the initial connection before the login screen is even displayed. I appear to be having hang ups in a few key locations but I can't identify the problem. I have a connection delay ranging from 20-30 seconds which eats up a lot of my customers time.

```
[root@NGCP ssh]# /usr/sbin/sshd -dddd -p 22
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 267
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 267
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:96 setting UseDNS no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:105 setting Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/sftp-server
debug3: checking syntax for 'Match user railcomm'
debug3: checking syntax for 'Match user maintenance'
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_4.9p1
debug1: private host key: #0 type 0 RSA1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 1 RSA
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: private host key: #2 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-dddd'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='22'
socket: Address family not supported by protocol
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.

Generating 768 bit RSA key.  <-- FOUR SECONDS

RSA key generation complete.
debug3: fd 4 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 7 config len 267
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 4 out 4 newsock 4 pipe -1 sock 7
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 10.40.50.156 port 59565
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version PuTTY_Release_0.66
debug1: no match: PuTTY_Release_0.66
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-1.99-OpenSSH_4.9
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: Network child is on pid 1051
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: privsep user:group 74:74
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,rsa2048-sha256,rsa1024-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,blowfish-ctr,blowfish-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,blowfish-ctr,blowfish-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 0
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 0
debug3: mm_answer_moduli: got parameters: 1024 4096 8192
debug3: mm_choose_dh: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_MODULI
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 1
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 1
debug3: mm_choose_dh: remaining 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
debug2: monitor_read: 0 used once, disabling now

debug3: mm_request_receive entering <-- FIVE SECONDS

debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 264/512
debug2: bits set: 1949/4096
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT

debug2: bits set: 2023/4096 <-- FIVE SECONDS

debug3: mm_key_sign entering
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_sign
debug3: mm_key_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 5
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: mm_answer_sign: signature 0x8005da00(271)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 5
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: KEX done
```

Comment: blind guessing : try `UseDNS No` in sshd options

Comment: I've noticed this with an Arch Linux Raspberry Pi. My current guess is that not enough entropy exists on the Raspberry Pi to do something - generate cryptographically secure random numbers, maybe? Didn't early Android phones have a pausing problem because of lack of entropy?

Comment: I tried the `UseDNS no` option

Comment: Bruce if you could explain that to me or link me to what that means I'd appreciate the knowledge.

Comment: Why is an RSA key being generated here? That should only happen on the first run. And 768 bits is too small nowadays, I wouldn't be comfortable with less than 2048. Which shouldn't take more than a few seconds even on an RPi1.